# Python: robust xpath for table in tr and td tags, eliminate unwanted data

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I need to robust way to get the xpath for this url `"http://www.screener.com/v2/stocks/view/5131"`

However, there are too many blank space before the desirable data in between and it is not robust.

The part I need is `11.48,9.05,11.53` from the html below:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Financial Year</th>
                                <th class="number">Revenue ('000)</th>
                                <th class="number">Net ('000)</th>
                                <th class="number">EPS</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                    <td>30 Nov, 2017</td>
                                    <td class="number">205,686</td>
                                    <td class="number">52,812</td>
                                    <td class="number">11.48</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                    <td>30 Nov, 2016</td>
                                    <td class="number">191,301</td>
                                    <td class="number">41,598</td>
                                    <td class="number">9.05</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                    <td>30 Nov, 2015</td>
                                    <td class="number">225,910</td>
                                    <td class="number">51,082</td>
                                    <td class="number">11.53</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
```

My code as below

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.screener.com/v2/stocks/view/5131')
output = html.fromstring(page.content)
output.xpath('//tr/td/following-sibling::td/text()')
```

How the code shall be change so that it can robustly get the three number from the tables as shown above?

I just want the output `11.48,9.05,11.53`but I unable to get rid of too many of the data inside teh tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath to get desired output:

```
//div[@id="annual"]//tr/td[position() = last() - 1]/text()
```

Comment: it still returns a bunch of unwanted data, although the desirable output is included. But i want to eliminate those unwanted data and only the desirable left

Comment: That's because there are several tables on page... Try `//div[@id="annual"]//tr/td[position() = last() - 1]/text()`

Comment: Could you elaborate more how it works? Just want to take the answer for answer. Thanks

Comment: `last()` stands for the index of last `td` in each `tr`. `td[position() = last()]` means *return the last `td` node in `tr`* and should return empty nodes (`<td></td>`) so we need to get not the `last()`, but `last() - 1` to get penultimate `td` with required values.